# How can I extract authorization roles using Easy Auth in a containerized App Service Blazor WebAssembly app?

Tags: .net, authentication, blazor, authorization, blazor-webassembly

I have a .NET 6.0 Blazor WASM app.  It is deployed to a docker container using Azure App Service.
Initially, the only requirement was Authenticating users.  I enabled the built-in authentication and authorization capabilities (sometimes referred to as "Easy Auth").  Great!  Now only authenticated users can access the deployed website.

When I run the application in Visual Studio there is now authentication or authorization going on.  Easy Auth does everything transparently after deployment.

Anyways, the requirements changed and now they want a level of authorization (one for view and one for view/edit).

I have done alot of research and have had mixed success.  Almost all tutorials assume you checked the **Authentication Type** - **Microsoft Identity Platform**.  Unfortunately, I did not have the foresight to do this, so I am trying to bolt on authorization after the fact.

I have found tutorials and libraries that purport to allow authorization from containerized applications using Easy Auth, but the always seems to be something other than Blazor WASM.  It also confirms this has been an on-going for challenge for developers for years.  Here are three great examples.

https://johnnyreilly.com/azure-container-apps-easy-auth-and-dotnet-authentication
https://blog.maximerouiller.com/post/using-easyauth-appservice-authentication-with-aspnet-core/
https://github.com/dasiths/NEasyAuthMiddleware

Unfortunately, I am never able to translate the code well enough to get it to work.
I did settle on writing my own **AuthenticationStateProvider** that reads the "/.auth/me" URL of the deployed web application and grabs what information I need.  I then mash the claims it into my ClaimsIdentity.    The mashing is required because  the "/.auth/me" stores the role authorization tokens in this format:
`"typ": "roles", "val": "Task.Write"`
which does not support direct insertion.

While the decorators `<AuthorizeView>` and gang now work. I cannot help but feel this is a bit cludgy and am hoping someone can guide me on a better way to do it for a Blazor WASM app.

```
    public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly UserService _userService;
        public CustomAuthStateProvider(UserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }
        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            string token = await _userService.GetAuthMeString();

            var parsedAuthMe = JArray.Parse(token);

            var realToken = parsedAuthMe[0]["id_token"].ToString();

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(realToken), "jwt");

            foreach (var claim in parsedAuthMe[0]["user_claims"])
            {
                if (claim["typ"].ToString() == "roles")
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, claim["val"].ToString()));
                }
                if (claim["typ"].ToString() == "name")
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, claim["val"].ToString()));
                }

            }

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var state = new AuthenticationState(user);

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));

            return state;
        }
}
```

```
    public class UserService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        public UserService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetAuthMeString()
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/.auth/me");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

            return null;
        }
}
```

Any advice for a more robust solution is appreciated!

Tried implementing all three of the above links but did not get far.  Ended up writing my own AuthenticationStateProvider and parsing the /.auth/me roles into it.

Comment: It is obvious you have to transform the claims. The way you are doing it is the correct way to handle this with middleware. To solve your "Bolt on problem" I would suggest making two solutions in different folders using the same namespaces. One with Auth one without. Commit both to git. Copy the Auth project over the other then use git to see the changes.